# play live stream videos on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, live-streaming

We would like to build an app for playing live stream videos.

What basically client have is an account on xtreme tv (not sure about link so not posting it). Now client want to live stream the video at the time of event. So we want to prepare an app where I can show the video.

I researched online and noticed that I can play mp4 videos, however my concern is live streaming will not be mp4 video. Even I am not sure what will be there for live streaming.

***It would be great if anyone tell me little details for live streaming videos?***

### [Might be this is the link client have](http://extreme.com/live)

Comment: Take a look at HTTP Live Streaming: https://developer.apple.com/streaming/. Your question is too broad.

Comment: @aergistal : thanks for your [link](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW556KW556&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ios%20streaming%20video)

Comment: There's a reason for being the first result on search. If you get a HLS stream then it's as easy as pointing MediaPlayer/AVFoundation to it. If not then you must find custom libs.  Your stream will also need to pass a validation test or you won't be allowed to publish the app.  Read the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MPMovieplayercontroller is more simple.
Just give it live video url. it will play by itself.
But video formatter should be ".m3u8". 
This is my experience. Share for you.

Comment: Thanks... Is there anything special to create m3u8 video?

Comment: i don't have too much knowledge about video formatter. i just put the live viedo on Microsoft Azure . And Microsoft Azure can pause this format for me